# UILocalNotification fire date computation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I having troubles with firing the `UILocalNotification`

I have a user input of 1 to 30 and I would like to use that to set as `firedate` for the `UILocalNotification`.

For example the user picked 5. I would like to set its `firedate` 5 days after the current date. How do you compute that?

Thank you.

Here's what I've done only so far.. Using this it goes for seconds only..

`notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:self.daysBeforeNotification];`

Comment: have you researched or tried anything?

Comment: Show what you have tried so we can help find the problem.

Comment: Look into: `-[NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents]`

Comment: Hi @SimonMcLoughlin, what I've tried only is `notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:self.daysBeforeNotification];` but it goes for seconds only..

Comment: @pretty_pau .... your telling me you can't figure out how to pass in x days in seconds ?????

Comment: Sorry people.. That's why I'm asking. Sorry for being a beginner kiddo. :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to accomplish this.

```
NSInteger daysToAdd = 5;
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:daysToAdd];
NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate  options:0];
```

Comment: Hey @Dima thanks for your help. Would try this out. Thank you so much.

Comment: As someone mentioned in the comments on your question, you can just use the method you tried as well. You would just need to multiply the days by each other unit to get to seconds (days * 60 * 60 * 24)

Comment: Hi @Dima, yes thanks it worked. Can you help me with my another problem? What I need to practice is that how would I know when to set the firedate between two given. For example. I set a target date of **JUNE 1, 2014** and I have another input of days before triggering the firedate for example i would set to to fire 1 day or 2 days before my target date. How can I do that using `NSTimeInterval` ? :)

Comment: Your question is not exactly to clear to me but in any case, you'll need to open up a new question to ask this.